# Cannot SSH to Raspberry Pi 3 with wired connection with Kubuntu laptop

Tags: networking, 16.04, ssh, raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate

Using SSH to connect my RPi3 to my gaming desktop running on Windows 10 with wired connection works fine.  My desktop doesn't have WiFi (just in case this is useful information).  I made sure of this by using remote desktop on my gaming PC, with RPi3's WiFi off, and the RPi3 remains connected to my desktop.

When I tried the same thing with my laptop (Kubuntu 17.04), I noticed that both laptop and RPi3 are still connected even with the cables disconnected.  Also, they can only connect with each other when I'm at home, but not anywhere else.  In addition, turning off WiFi on either device won't provide any connection whatsoever.

So, how do I fix it? How do I get SSH to work with only wired connection and not wireless?

Comment: Did you reload ssh after? service ssh reload

Answer (score 0):

You can configure openssh-server to only listen on a single interface by setting the ListenAddress config in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

If the IP address of your wired connection is X.X.X.X

just add the config line

`ListenAddress X.X.X.X`

You should also statically assign the wired interface in such a case as the IP could be subject to change if it is dynamically assigned.

Comment: It still says no route to host.  I add the ListenAddress on the Pi, right?